# svg "textLength" is not working with angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, angular7

```
const textElement = document.getElementById("id123");

if(textElement && textElement.textLength.baseVal.value){
    return Math.floor((node.width - textElement.textLength.baseVal.value) /2)
}
```

`textElement.textLength` is showing error while I am doing this in angular 7.

Error is:

> Property 'textLength' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Answer (score -1):

Typescript is typesafe. So the document.getElementById() returns the type HTMLElement which does not contain a value property. The subtype HTMLInputElement does however contain the value property.

So a solution is to cast the result of getElementById() to HTMLInputElement like this:

```
var temp = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("id123"));
```

<> is the casting operator in typescript. See the question TypeScript: casting HTMLElement.

The resulting javascript from the line above looks like this:

```
temp = (document.getElementById("id123"));
```